# What is the relation (equation) between mileage output and charging frequency of an electric vehicle?

Tags: battery-charging, electric-vehicle

What is the relation (equation) between output mileage (km/charge) and charging frequency (how many times an electric vehicle is charged in a day) of an electric vehicle?

Comment: More time it spends on charge the less miles it does...

Comment: Yes.. sure it does.. but is there any equation to denote the decrease in mileage with the number of times an EV is charged in a day (1,2,3,4... times)

Comment: I don't understand this - there's no km/liter number applicable for pure electric vehicles, and charging frequency does not impact the efficiency of the car?

Comment: "km/litre"? Per litre of what exactly? Electricity? Do you mean relationship between **range** and charging frequency? If so why would it not be *charge range x number of charges*? Hit the [edit] link and fix the question.

Comment: sorry... i meant km/charge... i wrote km by mistake.. now corrected mistake.. thanks to you Transistor

Comment: km/charge * charges/day = km/day.

Comment: Brian... will the mileage degrade on successive charging leading to a different result?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if this is what you meant, but I came up with this equation:
**Km-Per-Liter = avg. velocity * (24 - charging frequency * avg. charging time) / ((battery capacity / 8.76) * charging frequency)** where 8.76 is the conversion factor between kwh and liters of gasoline and the avg. charging time is from 0% to 100%. Do note that this would mean driving an entire day and always only recharging when the battery is at 0%. Also, if at midnight there still is any charge left it will lead to an efficiency drop. This equation also requires you start with empty batteries and therefore need to recharge at least once.